# Add a SKNode before calling SKView paused

Tags: swift, ios8, sprite-kit

Im trying to add a SKSpriteNode before pausing the scene. But currently my with my code the scene is paused so fast that there is no time to render the frame with the new SKSpiteNode. After the scene is un-paused the SKSpriteNode appears. How could I assure the SKSpriteNode is render before the scene is paused. Here is my code:

```
func pauseScene() {

    if (self.scene?.view?.paused == true){
        self.pauseNode.removeFromParent()
        self.scene?.view?.paused = false
    } else if (self.scene?.view?.paused == false){
        pauseTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "pauseImage")
        pauseTexture.filteringMode = SKTextureFilteringMode.Nearest
        pauseNode = SKSpriteNode(texture: pauseTexture)
        pauseNode.zPosition = 100
        pauseNode.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y: CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
        pauseNode.size = CGSize(width: screenSize.width, height: screenSize.height)
        self.addChild(pauseNode)
        self.scene?.view?.paused = true
    }

}
```

Comment: you could defer the pausing of the view to a runBlock: action in a sequence with a leading "wait" action that waits for 0 seconds (if I remember correctly a wait action with 0 duration still defers execution to the next frame)

Comment: If not too much, create two different nodes: game/worldNode and hudNode.  Put the game objects in worldNode and add pause node in hudNode. If want to pause the game, pause the worldNode.

Comment: I added the runBlock with the wait for 0 sec. Worked perfectly, thank you